# Why android studio uninstall previously installed application forcefully from emulator every time when I run application

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Why android studio uninstalls previously installed application forcefully from emulator every time when I run the application. because of this, all my data in the app is reset.how can I solve this problem?

Comment: create a new emulator and select Cold boot option for the emulator. Select device frame which does not have play console icon so you can customize the RAM for emulator. I think this can resolve your problem.